# Open Barebones IE with Shortcut

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, desktop

Is there a method to launch an Internet Explorer window from a desktop Icon such that the Status Bar and tool bar are hidden?

When a user clicks on the icon only the windows form (Maximize, Minimize etc) icons should be present. The URL bar, Toolbar, Status bar should not be present.

Comment: not sure if this will do what you need which is why i am adding it as a comment but using the commandline argument -k will open the browser fullscreen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a VB script, shudder...

```
Dim objIE
Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")
ObjIE.Toolbar = false
objIE.Navigate "about:blank"
objIE.Visible = true
```

Save that as ie.vbs

Comment: Does the user need anything special loaded to have this vb script work?

Comment: It requires Windows Script Host, which is included with windows: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host#Version_history

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple program to do it, which you could create a shortcut to.

The basic outline would be:

```
CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> webbrowser;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **)&webbrowser);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
  webbrowser->put_AddressBar(VARIANT_FALSE);
  webbrowser->put_StatusBar(VARIANT_FALSE);
  webbrowser->put_ToolBar(VARIANT_FALSE);
  webbrowser->put_MenuBar(VARIANT_FALSE);
  webbrowser->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shortcut to a webpage that uses [javascript to open a new window](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_open.asp) without status or toolbars and then close the original window.

```
var newWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no");
window.close();
```

Comment: Good idea.  The user will be prompted on the window.close(), though.

Comment: And it will still have an address bar (for security reasons).

Comment: @Mark I didn't realize IE would prompt you on window.close(), thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an intermediate page that configures IE that way using javascript and then redirects to the real target URL. I believe you use `window.Externals` to access the toolbars.